# Renaming an illegal variable which contains an apostrophe

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I am currently trying to create a macro which will rename variables by replacing all instances of special characters with an underscore. I have come across a specific issue where I am getting an error message because a variable name contains "'". More explicitly,

> Suppose we were to have a variable name "dumm'y?", under my macro, this should be renamed to "dumm_y_". The problem is that when I come to performing the renaming what SAS tries to compute is: `rename 'dumm'y?'n = dumm_y_"`. The issue is the apostrophe in the variable name causes SAS to produce an error message.

I have tried to replace the apostrophe with an underscore using `TRANSLATE(name, "_", "'")`, though this causes errors since SAS will be performing `RENAME 'dumm_y?'n = "dumm_y_'` as `dumm_y?` is not a variable name within the database I am trying to rename.

I know that by replacing all instances of  `'` into a `"`, vice versa, in `name = cats("'", name, "'n")` will resolve this issue. Though the problem will still remain if the variable name were `dumm"y?`.

N.B. I know that by changing SAS variable name policy to V7 will effectively resolve this issue. I am intentionally creating this macro to improve on my SAS skills.

```
/* Generate dummy data */
option validvarname = any;
data dummy_data;
    input "dumm'y?"n;
    datalines;
    1 
    2 
    3
    ;
run;


data badvarname (keep = name validname);
    set sashelp.vcolumn;
    where libname = "WORK" and memname = "DUMMY_DATA";
    
    validname = prxchange("s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/", -1, trim(name));

/* Replacing the apostrophe with an underscore still causes an error */
/*      name = translate(name, "_", "'");  */
    name = cats("'", name, "'n"); 
run;


proc sql;
    select cats("rename", name, "=", validname, ";") into : renamelist
    separated by " " from badvarname;
quit;


data output_tab;
    set dummy_data;
    &renamelist.;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the NLITERAL() function to convert the NAME in the metadata into the syntax that is valid for use in SAS code.  Do not include the RENAME keyword in the generated macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
select catx('=',nliteral(name),nliteral(validname))
  into :renamelist separated by ' '
from badvarname;
quit;

...
  rename &renamelist ;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the NLITERAL function.

```
name = nliteral(name);
```